# Prevent `chan::Receiver` from blocking on empty buffer

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel, rust-tokio

I'd like to build an Multi-Producer Multi-Consumer (MPMC) channel with different concurrent tasks processing and producing data in it. Some of these tasks have the responsibility to interface with the filesystem or network.

Two examples:

- `PrintOutput(String)` would be consumed by a logger, a console output, or a GUI.
- `NewJson(String)` would be consumed by a logger or a parser.

To achieve this, I've selected `chan` as the MPMC channel provider and `tokio` as the system to manage event loops for each listener on the channel.

After reading the example on [tokio's site](https://tokio.rs/), I began to implement `futures::stream::Stream` for `chan::Receiver`. This would allow the use of a for each future to listen on the channel. However, the documentation of these two libraries highlights a conflict:

> ### `fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error>`
>
> Attempt to pull out the next value of this stream, returning None if the stream is finished.
>
> This method, like Future::poll, is the sole method of pulling out a value from a stream. This method must also be run within the context of a task typically and implementors of this trait must **ensure that implementations of this method do not block**, as it may cause consumers to behave badly.

> ### `fn recv(&self) -> Option<T>`
>
> Receive a value on this channel.
>
> If this is an asnychronous channel, recv only **blocks when the buffer is empty.**
>
> If this is a synchronous channel, recv only blocks when the buffer is empty.
>
> If this is a rendezvous channel, recv blocks until a corresponding send sends a value.
>
> For all channels, if the channel is closed and the buffer is empty, then recv always and immediately returns None. (If the buffer is non-empty on a closed channel, then values from the buffer are returned.)
>
> Values are guaranteed to be received in the same order that they are sent.
>
> This operation will never panic! but it can deadlock if the channel is never closed.

`chan::Receiver` may block when the buffer is empty, but `futures::stream::Stream` expects to never block when polled.

If an empty buffer blocks, there isn't a clear way to confirm that it is empty. How do I check if the buffer is empty to prevent blocking?

Although [Kabuki](https://github.com/carllerche/kabuki/blob/master/README.md) is on my radar and seems to be the most mature of the actor model crates, it almost entirely lacks documentation.

---

This is my implementation so far:

```
extern crate chan;
extern crate futures;

struct RX<T>(chan::Receiver<T>);

impl<T> futures::stream::Stream for RX<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type Error = Box<std::error::Error>;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> futures::Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        let &mut RX(ref receiver) = self;
        let item = receiver.recv();

        match item {
            Some(value) => Ok(futures::Async::Ready(Some(value))),
            None => Ok(futures::Async::NotReady),
        }
    }
}
```

I've finished a quick test to see how it works. It seems alright, but as expected does block after finishing the buffer. While this should work, I'm somewhat worried about what it means for a consumer to "behave badly". For now I'll continue to test this approach and hopefully I don't encounter bad behaviour.

```
extern crate chan;
extern crate futures;
use futures::{Stream, Future};

fn my_test() {
    let mut core = tokio_core::reactor::Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    let (tx, rx) = chan::async::<String>();

    tx.send("Hello".to_string()); // fill the buffer before it blocks; single thread here.

    let incoming = RX(rx).for_each(|s| {
        println!("Result: {}", s);

        Ok(())
    });

    core.run(incoming).unwrap()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chan` crate provides a [`chan_select`](https://docs.rs/chan/0.1.19/chan/macro.chan_select.html) macro that would allow a non-blocking `recv`; but to implement `Future` for such primitives you also need to wake up the task when the channel becomes ready (see [`futures::task::current()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.16/futures/task/fn.current.html)).

You can implement `Future` by using existing primitives; implementing new ones is usually more difficult.  In this case you probably have to fork `chan` to make it `Future` compatible.

It seems the `multiqueue` crate has a `Future` compatible mpmc channel [`mpmc_fut_queue`](https://docs.rs/multiqueue/0.3.2/multiqueue/fn.mpmc_fut_queue.html).

Comment: Oh, `mpmc_fut_queue` seems like exactly what I'd been looking for! I managed to get `chan` working for my use-case because a thread being blocked until a new message arrives is easy to deal with; just send a `Terminate` message when everything's finished.